# Subtracting value in one column from the date in another column

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have tried:

```
add_months('date_column',  -'number_of_months_column')
```

I get:

> error [3535] A character string failed conversion to a numeric value.

Is what I am trying to do possible with the `add_months` option?

Comment: Please post sample data and expected output

Comment: What are the data types of the two columns? Is the first one in fact a DATE and the second numeric (e.g. INTEGER)? Seems at least one is a character string and an implicit data type conversion is being attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use single quotes around column names?

If `number_of_months_column`'s data type is `integer` then this should work:

```
add_months(date_column, -number_of_months_column)
```

If `number_of_months_column` is a string then you must convert it first to an integer:

```
add_months(date_column, -to_number(number_of_months_column))
```

or:

```
add_months(date_column, -cast(to_number(number_of_months_column) as integer))
```

or:

```
add_months(date_column, -trycast(to_number(number_of_months_column) as integer))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe it is possible. But you need to make sure that the 2nd argument is a numeric data type. Based on the error, it looks like some records cannot be implicitly converted to a numeric.

The following details are from the Teradata Documentation regarding [Error  3535](https://docs.teradata.com/r/GVKfXcemJFkTJh_89R34UQ/EdEtDim_bFUi227nLtva0A) and its solution.

> **Explanation:**
>
> A character string constant in a query is in a context requiring that
> it represent a numeric value, and it does not.
>
> **Remedy:**
>
> Change the constant to either a numeric value or a character string
> that represents a numeric value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you update your answer with a quote from the link you are referring to? Otherwise, in case the link becomes invalid, your answer will be of no use to others. Thanks!